# clastering one dimension data with unknown distance metric

Tags: algorithm

I have a 2-dimensional array which describes the distance between objects:

```
    A    B    C
A   0    1    2
B   1    0    3
C   2    3    0
```

for example distance(A,B) = 1, distance(B,C) = 3, distance(A,C) = 2,
distance(x,y) = distance(x,y). I do not know anything more about this distance, it is not Euclides Distance or any commonly known distance function.

How to find number of groups and partition points (x,y)?

Comment: Possible duplicated with http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/clustering-with-a-distance-matrix

Comment: In my question importent is that the distance is not Euklides, what is more I do not know any think about distance. K-mean algorithm and moust that I find in google need Euklides distance between points.

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution:

```
D =[x][y] #two dimencion array with distances between x and y 
sorted_distance = sorted_distance(D) # all values apears in D, delete duplicates and sort from max to min value

for distance in sorted_distance:
    V = D.keys()
    E = []
    for x in V:
        for y in V:
            if x==y: continue
            if D[x][y]<=distance:
                E.append((x,y))
    G = Grapth(V,E)
    connected_components = get_connected_components(G)
    if len(connected_components)>1: # this value could be increase if result is not rewarding
        return connected_components
```